# Calculating percentage change in Power BI area chart for specific field toggle values across years

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power Bi - How to get percentage change in area chart where x-axis is Year and y-axis is a toggle.
What I want is the percentage change in every year of the particular field coming in from toggle.
[A screenshot of visual here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owm3b.png)

This is what I tried in DAX

```
Toggle % difference from Revenue = 
VAR __BASELINE_VALUE = CALCULATE([Toggle], 'Table1'[Column1] IN { "Revenue" })
VAR __MEASURE_VALUE = [Toggle]
RETURN
    IF(
        NOT ISBLANK(__MEASURE_VALUE),
        DIVIDE(__MEASURE_VALUE - __BASELINE_VALUE, __BASELINE_VALUE)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a separate date/calendar table if you haven't already.

```
Calendar = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Create a relationship between this and the date column of your data table.

```
VAR CurrentMonthValue =
    CALCULATE([Toggle], 'Table1'[Column1] IN { "Revenue" })
VAR PreviousMonthValue =
    CALCULATE (
        [Toggle], 
        'Table1'[Column1] IN { "Revenue" },
        DATEADD('Calendar'[Date],-1,YEAR)
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( CurrentMonthValue - PreviousMonthValue, PreviousMonthValue )
```

This will take the percentage change of the toggle measure over the same period of time one year prior.